# Seeking Intuitions about Recursion, Y Combinator and System F

Tags: computability, lambda-calculus, computation-models

So, as I understand things, System F (polymorphic lambda calculus) doesn't have the Y Combinator and isn't Turing Complete, but it is very expressive. This answer (https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/29519/what-functions-can-system-f-not-compute), plus others, have given me the impression that there's nothing too obvious one can point to and say, "That's not definable by System F".

But I don't fully understand how this works in relation to recursion. As I understand it, the Y Combinator is the magic trick that allows for anonymous recursion in lambda calculus (as opposed to the named function recursion that happens in most modern programming languages). So what would Fibonacci look like in System F without the Y Combinator? At a high-level of abstraction, I first guessed it would have to work as follows:

```
fib (x):
    if x <= 1: return handle_base_case()
    else return fib_1(x-1) + fib_2(x-2)
```

where `fib_1(x)` then defines `fib_3` and `fib_4` and so on, i.e.  you don't have 'true' recursion but have to define a separate expression for each function call.

One thing I note about this implementation is that you can't really implement it explicitly for any arbitrary x (despite my notation). Because the actual explicit implementation would get longer for every higher value of x, due to having to define more nestings.

Alternatively, does System F allow you to do this?

```
let fib : (Nat -> Nat) -> Nat -> Nat = 
    \f n -> 
        if (n == 0) 
        then 0 
        else if (n == 1) 
             then 1 
             else f (n-1) + f (n-2)
```

You could invoke this like so `fib fib x` for any `x`. This doesn't use the Y Combinator, but it is a truly recursive algorithm. So is this allowed in System F?

I guess I also have a broader question to answer: how bad would it be if, as a computer programmer, you had to program in System F? What would be the biggest pain points?

Comment: isn't `fib fib x` ill-typed?
the first argument to `fib` is of type `Nat -> Nat` but `fib` is of type `(Nat -> Nat) -> Nat -> Nat`

For your last question: programming in System F would be very similar to programming in Assembly. You could do it, but it would be really painful.